# Change syntax ul, li, span

Tags: php, html, nette

Focus please where start tag

```
    <ul class="checkbox-list checkbox-list--custom">
        <li class="test container container--sm" n:foreach="$answers as $key => $answer">
            <input type="checkbox" disabled n:attr="checked => $isChecked($key)">
            <span n:class="$isCorrect($key) ? 'text-success', $isIncorrect($key) ? 'test1'">
                {$answer->getAnswerText()}
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I would like move content inside span element to li element

This is [current status](https://screenshots.firefox.com/bBRVoIQwA9av2IzX/localhost)
This is [required status](https://screenshots.firefox.com/aBQ7nKARrGUBrZx5/preview.uxpin.com)

Comment: Why do you need the span? Just apply the class to the `li` element

Comment: I dont need span element, but need code what is inside in <span

Comment: What's stopping you from moving it?

Comment: If i modify my code
<li class="test container container--sm" n:foreach="$answers as $key => $answer" n:class="$isCorrect($key) ? 'text-success', $isIncorrect($key) ? 'test1'">

Have this error https://screenshots.firefox.com/2ek6tuFNbqOrCHAN/localhost

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, you cannot currently mix `class` and `n:class` attributes in a single element. However, you can move the classes from the `class` attribute to `n:class` and that should work:

```
<ul class="checkbox-list checkbox-list--custom">
    <li n:foreach="$answers as $key => $answer" n:class="test, container, container--sm, $isCorrect($key) ? text-success, $isIncorrect($key) ? test1">
        <input type="checkbox" disabled n:attr="checked => $isChecked($key)">
        {$answer->getAnswerText()}
    </li>
</ul>
```

It also should not be necessary to quote the classes in `n:class` attribute.